# Criterion for Irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Recently my lecture introduced a criterion for the reducibility polynomials:

Let $R$ be an [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain), $p \in R$ prime element (notice that in an UFD $p$ prime $\Leftrightarrow p$ irreducible), $f \in R[X],\,f \neq 0, p \nmid a_n$ ($f$'s leading coefficient).

$$
\varphi: R[X] \rightarrow R/(p)[X]\,\,\,\,\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iX^i \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} \bar{a_i}X^i
$$

- $f$ is irreducible in Quot($R$)[X] if $\varphi(f)$ is irreducible in $R/(p)[X]$
- $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$ if $\varphi(f)$ is irreducible in $R/(p)[X]$ and $f$ is primitive

Now I'm wondering why more requirements are necessary to show that $f$ is irreducible in $R[X]$. For me it would be more intuitive, if more requirements would be necessary to show that f is irreducible in Quot($R$)[X].

Isn't it true, that every reducible polynomial in $R[X]$ is also reducible in Quot($R$)$[X]$ and also that every irreducible polynomial in Quot($R$)[X] is also irreducible in $R[X]$? I think I misunderstand something crucial here.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590227/1-x3-x5-irreducible-in-mathbbzx/2590232?noredirect=1#comment5347896_2590232).

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you mean specifically? Should I look at the proof? Also why do people downvote my question without leaving feedback at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f = 2 \cdot T \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ is reducible (because $2$,$T$ are no units),

but $f = 2 \cdot T \in \mathbb{Q}[T]$ is irreducible (because $T$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ and $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$).

So you can see that not every factorization of a polynomial in not-units in $R[T]$ is a factorization in not-units in $Quot(R)[T]$.